# How to stretch a div to available width after a wrapped text?

Tags: html, css

I need an underline that occupies all the remaining width after some wrapped text. And all this in a table cell.

Here is what I want:

[image]

And of course if the text wraps differently (due to resize or whatever), the underline width must change accordingly.

And what it shows:

[image]

My code is:

```css
.uln {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:220px; text-align:justify">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>this is a very long text. this is a very long text. this is a very long text. this is a very long text. this is a very long text. this is a very long text. this is a very long text. this is a very long text. this is a very long text.</span>
      <div class="uln">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the underline in full length and paint the text over the line, so that it is hidden where the text is.

```css
.with-blank {
  position: relative;
}

.with-blank::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
}

.with-blank span {
  z-index: 2;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:220px; text-align:justify">
  <tr>
    <td class="with-blank">
      <span>this is a very long text. this is a very long text. this is a very long text. this is a very long text. this is a very long text. this is a very long text. this is a very long text. this is a very long text. this is a very long text.</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
td {
  position: relative;
}

span {
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.uln {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 4px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:220px; text-align:justify">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>this is a very long text. this is a very long text. this is a very long text. this is a very long text. this is a very long text. this is a very long text. this is a very long text. this is a very long text. this is a very long text.</span>
      <div class="uln">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```